# Add a prefix to all url's of the WordPress website except the homepage

Tags: home-url

I have a website at the moment, f.e. website.com. 
The last weeks we also created 2 translation websites: website.de and website.nl. In 2020 a lot of other domains will follow.

That's why we would like to make from website.com an overview of all domains. There the visitor can go to website.de, website.nl and other domains that will follow.

**What is the best way to add at the current website (website.com) everywhere an prefix /global/ (f.e. website.com/global & website.com/global/contact)? The last step is to create an overview page of all the domains in the same WordPress website. So there shouldn't be the prefix /global/.**

If a visitor is f.e. at website.com/global/contact and he clicks in on home or the logo in the menu that it goes to website.com/global and not website.com.

I'm struggling what the best way is to realize this.

Cheers

Comment: I will try to explain the question a bit more clearer. I need to have a page before my index page in WordPress. It shouldn't affect the SEO-results of the index and other pages.